# HTML Form Data not Recognized when Clicking Submit using VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, webforms

I have a form that I'm filling out using data from a spreadsheet. I have everything working correctly, but when I hit submit (either manually or via code), the validation on the site doesn't recognize that the form is filled out. It errors out stating that the text boxes/combo boxes are all blank. How do I refresh so that it knows there is data populated? I apologize in advance if the code is amateurish, but this is my first pass at interacting with web forms.

Here is the code:

```
Sub AddNewDevice()

    Dim objCollection As Object

    For Each wd In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows

        If wd = "Internet Explorer" Then
            If InStr(UCase(wd.document.Title), "ADD A NEW CISCO ACS") <> 0 Then
                'Debug.Print "Yes"
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next wd
    wd.Visible = True

    Set objCollection = wd.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    i = 0
    While i < objCollection.Length
        'Name
        If objCollection(i).Name = "Y__0__Cctl1_ctl8_ctl2_6_ctl4__X" Then
            objCollection(i).Value = Sheets("Main").Range("b4")
        End If
        'Description
        If objCollection(i).Name = "Y__0__Cctl1_ctl8_ctl2_7_ctl4__X" Then
            objCollection(i).Value = Sheets("Main").Range("b5")
        End If
        'IP Address/Subnet
        If objCollection(i).Name = "Y__0__Cctl1_ctl8_ctl2_11_ctl4__X" Then
            objCollection(i).Value = Sheets("Main").Range("b6")
        End If
        'TACACS+
        If objCollection(i).Name = "Y__0__Cctl1_ctl8_wctl1_2_ColumnEditor1__X" Then
            objCollection(i).Click
        End If
        'Shared Secret
        If objCollection(i).Name = "Y__0__Cctl1_ctl8_wctl1_3_ColumnEditor1__X" Then
            objCollection(i).Value = Sheets("Main").Range("B22")
        End If
        'Single Connect
        If objCollection(i).Name = "Y__0__Cctl1_ctl8_wctl1_4_ColumnEditor1__X" And _
            Sheets("Main").Range("B25") = "Yes" Then
            objCollection(i).Click
        End If
        'Legacy TACACS+
        If objCollection(i).Name = "Y__0__Cctl1_ctl8_wctl1_5_ColumnEditor1__X" And _
            Sheets("Main").Range("B25") = "Yes" Then
            objCollection(i).Click
        End If
       i = i + 1
    Wend
    Set objCollection = Nothing
    Set objCollection = wd.document.getElementsByTagName("select")
    i = 0
    While i < objCollection.Length
        'Location
        If objCollection(i).Name = "Y__0__C22_ctl8_ctl2_8_ctl4_wctl1__X" Then
            objCollection(i).selectedIndex = Sheets("Main").Range("B23")
        End If
        'Device Type
        If objCollection(i).Name = "Y__0__C22_ctl8_ctl2_9_ctl4_wctl1__X" Then
            objCollection(i).selectedIndex = Sheets("Main").Range("B24")
        End If
        'DSR and Above
        If objCollection(i).Name = "Y__0__C22_ctl8_ctl2_10_ctl4_ctl1__X" Then
            objCollection(i).selectedIndex = 2
        End If
       i = i + 1
    Wend
    Set submitButton = wd.document.getElementById("Y__0__Cctl10___X")
        'submitButton.Click
    Set objCollection = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: I would guess that the form is using hidden fields to capture the data. It's pretty common for a web form to update a hidden field with a value when the visible field is updated, but the event won't (usually) fire when you change the data programatically.

You should be able to fire whatever function is called by the field being updated in code (using window.eval).

Comment: Thanks C. White. I've never used window.eval. Could you provide some guidance? I did find some hidden fields but not enough to have one for each corresponding visible field. here are two that stick out     <input type="hidden" name="aeweb_runtimeFormID" id="aeweb_runtimeFormID" value="3fcee193-280c-4541-afb1-304926892d83" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE"

Comment: Eval **should** just call whatever javascript function you pass it (so if you see some sort of event in the main control that fires when you update the control, you could just call it). You should also be able to set `aeweb_runtimeFormID` to whatever value you need (provided you can figure out what value that is).